# Vim run command in background, but show output live in vsplit

Tags: vim, script, gvim

How can I run a terminal command (for instance build) in vim while working on a file, while simultaneously showing the output live in a vsplit?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch

Comment: thanks, ill have a look at it, I just thought I heard vim now supports asynchronous tasks by default

Comment: Yes it does, @philosopher.stoned gave an example. The plugin just wraps around this functionality (and provides fallback for old Vim versions). In my opinion it has a nice interface and is easier to use than raw Vim commands.

Comment: dokes this also work in gvim? cuz it says I need tmux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [job_start function](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/channel.txt.html#job-start) for this. It'll invoke your command in a separate process instance. You can pass buffer names to this call and vim will link STDOUT and STDERR pipes of job's process to these buffers.
A host of additional actions are also possible, like registering callbacks when data is posted to these buffers, type of job being run, etc.

```
Example:
        let logjob = job_start("tail -f /tmp/log",
                             \ {'out_io': 'buffer', 'out_name': 'dummy'})
        vsplit | buffer dummy
```

Comment: this works really well, thanks. Is there a way to always keep the buffer at the very end to always see the output

Comment: Use vim movement command 'G' to go to end of buffer. Once at end, it'll always track new data being added and scroll automatically.